# How to make a standalone sails.js bundle using nexe?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I seek a simple way to protect the code of sail.js app (0.12) using nexe tool. To the moment I am able to include contents of sailsjs config files to the nexe.js. However I did not find a simple solution for including controllers, models and hooks of sails.js to the bundle.

Perhaps somebody has experience with nodejs+sailsjs+nexe, or can give more detailed information about proper usage of marlinespike module.

Comment: A convenient solution exists for a specific version of Sails.js (0.12.8) following such a way:

Answer (score 0):

I think that's impossible. Sails does a lot of `fs.readFileSync` and it's kinda impossible to bundle everything. Not to mention the whole grunt-based build system.

One good approach would be to minify every file ( controller, models, etc. ) and maintain the same directory structure. Keep in mind that some variable names in sails also matter for the end result, so you should throughly test your app.

Comment: I wish to bundle only proprietary algorithms in the api folder for production mode. In that mode I disable grunt and just manually deploy assets. As for minifying, modern IDEs and web-browsers are so clever, that can restore the code almost completely :)

Answer (score 0):

A convenient solution exists for a specific version of Sails.js (0.12.8) following such a way:

### in app.js

1) preload all needed controllers like

```
 var controller_1 = require('api/controllers/DesignController.js');
var controller_n = ....
```

2) preload all configs like

```
    var routes=  require('./config/routes').routes;
var blueprints =  require('./config/blueprints').blueprints;
var connections =  require('./config/connections').connections;
var cors =  require('./config/cors').cors;
var csrf =  require('./config/csrf').csrf;
var globals=  require('./config/globals').globals;
....
```

3) load and create instance of Sails using a special form of require (provided by nexe):

```
    var incSails = 'sails';
var Sails = GLOBAL.require(incSails).constructor;
var sailsApp = new Sails();
```

4) lift sails with preloaded configs and disabled Grunt. Then in the callback force loading of the routes.

```
sailsApp.lift({"routes": routes,
            "http":http,
            "i18n":i18n,
            "local":local,
            "cors":cors,
            "csrf":csrf,
            "sockets":sockets,
            "log":log,
            "views":views,
            "session":session,
            "connections":connections,
            "blueprints":blueprints,
            "policies":policies,
            "globals": globals,
            "hooks": { "grunt": false }
}, 
function (err) {
var controllers = {"actions":{}, "Design": controller_1, .... "...":          controller_n};
var transformed = transformEntities(controllers);
sails['controllers'] = transformed;
sails.hooks.controllers.loadAndRegisterControllers(function cb() { });
sails.router.load(function cb(){ } )
```

}
   );

5) one internal function is needed (which is actually a clone from some module)

```
 function transformEntities(entities) {
 var res1 =  _.mapValues(entities, function (entity, key)  {
  return _.defaults(entity, {
  globalId: key,
  identity: key.toLowerCase()
 })
});
 var res2 = _.mapKeys(res1, function (entity, key)  {
 return key.toLowerCase();
 });
 return res2;
}
```

### Next steps

compile the app by nexe.

copy the compiled file to a test folder together with node_modules.

start the compiled file (the sails server will be launched).

access the server by the routes specified.